Browser push notification received but never triggers
Using webpush, just a quick and dirty POC to see if i can get push notifications to work. index.html just has two buttons, one to subscribe, one to test the push notification.
I have sufficient logs to see that the subscription happens. Clicking notify does post to /notify and returns a 200. I generated keys (pair is in server.js, the public key is in index.html)
Chrome outputs the worker's console.log's, but neither Chrome nor Firefox actually fire the push notification.
Running this locally on port 3000 (node server.js) and then I have an A record pointing to a subdomain I have a reverse proxy (nginx proxy manager) running to force SSL (with websockets enabled if that matters). So I'm accessing this from a valid certificate https://sub.mydomain.com in Chrome and Firefox, but the push notification never actually fires.
I'm certain push notifications are allowed in browser settings, the subscription works to enable the permission for the domain. I even tried enabling service worker debugging in Firefox--no dice.
server.js
const express = require('express');
const webpush = require('web-push');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Serve static files from the 'public' directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

const publicVapidKey = 'my pub key';
const privateVapidKey = 'my priv key';

webpush.setVapidDetails('mailto:noreply@mydomain.com', publicVapidKey, privateVapidKey);

let subscriptions = [];

app.post('/subscribe', (req, res) => {
    const subscription = req.body;
    subscriptions.push(subscription);
    console.log('subscriptions: ', subscriptions);
    res.status(201).json({});
});

app.post('/notify', (req, res) => {
    console.log('hit /notify');

    const payload = JSON.stringify({
        title: 'New Notification',
        message: 'You have a new notification!'
    });

    subscriptions.forEach(sub => {
        webpush.sendNotification(sub, payload).catch(err => {
            console.error('Error sending notification:', err);
        });
    });
    res.status(200).json({});
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});

worker.js
self.addEventListener('push', event => {
    console.log('push received');
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.data);
    console.log(event.data.json());
    const data = event.data.json();
    // debugger;
    self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
        body: data.message,
        icon: '/icon.png'
    });
    // tried this too:
    //const notification = new Notification(data.title, {
    //    body: data.message,
    //    icon: '/icon.png'
    //});
});

index.html (relevant parts)
// Subscribe for push notifications
        async function subscribeUser() {
            const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/worker.js', { scope: '/' });
            const subscription = await registration.pushManager.subscribe({
                userVisibleOnly: true,
                applicationServerKey: urlBase64ToUint8Array(publicVapidKey)
            });
            await fetch('/subscribe', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(subscription),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            });
            alert('Subscribed successfully!');
        }

        // Send a test notification
        async function sendNotification() {
            await fetch('/notify', { method: 'POST' });
        }

        function urlBase64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
            const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
            const base64 = (base64String + padding).replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
            const rawData = window.atob(base64);
            return Uint8Array.from([...rawData].map((char) => char.charCodeAt(0)));
        }

        document.getElementById('subscribe').addEventListener('click', subscribeUser);
        document.getElementById('notify').addEventListener('click', sendNotification);


FYI: I do all my testing using http://localhost:3000 (port number is not relevant) - which, in Firefox at least, works, so no need for messing around with reverse proxies, ssl certificates etc just for development

your /notify route returns 200 OK in every case. Did you actually check your backend, if webpush.sendNotification reported an error?

@derpirscher no errors ok the backend from what i can see. ive sprinkled console.log's all over

Ah, I missed the part where you wrote "Chrome outputs the worker's console.log's, but neither Chrome nor Firefox actually fire the push notification." So, if I understand correctly, you actually receive the push event on the client side, but the notification is not shown?

If that's the case, you should be able to debug your worker.js and set a breakpoint in the eventhandler if that throws any errors ...   Attach to your worker by opening the developer tools for your site, and then in the "Applications" tab you will see the "service workers" rather on top.

@derpirscher ive set a debugger in the worker. no errors. i even added a console.log after self.registration.showNotification...--debugs right over it, nothing in the console. can i look somewhere else for errors?

The problem is that you are not handling the push event correctly... look at some real code used for web push: https://pushpad.xyz/service-worker.js As you can see there is also a event.waitUntil(), which is necessary... Otherwise your code ends before displaying the notification!
